# Curly Bracket Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have come across this a lot in ExtJS and I was wondering where it's coming from I have an example like this:

```
 view: new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
        forceFit:true,
        groupTextTpl: '{text} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]})'
    }),
```

Where is {text} coming from in this function? It's not been set like var text; anywhere in the script. Can I manipulate it like a normal string? Any insight on this would be helpful,

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a template.  Somewhere in the rest of the code, the {text} in that string will be replaced with a value at run time.

**Update**:

Okay, look, you can do pretty much anything you want with it.  I've don't have Ext.js handy so I can't give you straight-up code. but that argument is just an anonymous object.  The `new` operation there creates an object, and uses that stuff as part of the contents. `view`  will become the name of an attribute attached to SOMETHING -- to the window object if nothing else -- naming that new object.

If you want to know what's in it, `console.dir` in a debugger should dump out the contents.  In those contents is almost certainly a string named `groupTextTpl`, and that's just a string, do with it as you will.

More probably, though, read up on template processing in Ext.js -- you can probably write code to use that template and make new, customized coipies from it.

Comment: Thank you for your information, is it possible to manipulate it? Like use a substring function

Comment: You might be able to replace `{text}` with `{[values.text.substring(0, 1)]}` and so forth. If not, implementing a http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Template will let you  add a breakpoint-able function to have a poke around at what you can do.

Comment: you can do pretty much anything you like with it.... I'm going to add more to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's ah `Object` with two key-value pairs:
1. key: `forceFit`, value: `true`
2. key: `groupTextTpl`, value: `'{text} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]})'`
second one is a string btw

Comment: You've misread his question. He's referring to the `{text}` in the `groupTextTpl` property.

Comment: then the first answer is right: it's an expression stored as string