# Why use var { VariableName } = require('') in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, coding-style, firefox-addon-sdk

I have seen lot of examples in Firefox [addon-sdk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/dev-guide/index.html) which uses the below style when declaring a variable.

```
var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");
```

What difference it makes with `var { Hotkey }` than using `var HotKey`? Why the extra flower brackets are used?

Comment: Don't know myself, but this might have some information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445496/curly-bracket-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29).

```
var {Hotkey} = require('sdk/hotkeys');
```

is equivalent to:

```
var Hotkey = require('sdk/hotkeys').Hotkey;
```

See also the [harmony:destructuring](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adestructuring) proposal, which includes the following examples:

```
// object destructuring
var { op: a, lhs: b, rhs: c } = getASTNode()

// digging deeper into an object
var { op: a, lhs: { op: b }, rhs: c } = getASTNode()
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept from CoffeeScript: http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring. I believe ECMAScript may adopt something similar (which is why it may already be appearing in Firefox add-ons).

Comment: Thanks. Destructing assignment sounds interesting. However, I don't see a similar example like `var {Hotkey} = require('sdk/hotkeys');` in the documentation link that you have pointed to.

Comment: `var {op: a} = getASTNode()` is equivalent to `var a = getASTNode().op`. The token to the left of the ":" is the property name and the token to the right of the ":" is the variable name. Often, though, one wishes to use the same name in both cases, as in `var {Hotkey: Hotkey} = require('sdk/hotkeys')`. Because this is a common pattern, there's a shorthand: `var {Hotkey} = require('sdk/hotkeys')`.

Comment: destructuring has been around in Mozilla's enhanced versions of JS for a long time - there are a number of Mozilla-specific extensions to JS that are also finding their way into Harmony such as array comprehensions and generators.